# How can I draw a circle using linerenderer and make it the circle as object child of the object is should draw around?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I attach this script to an object it will draw a circle around it.
Now I want to make that the script the linerenderer will be attached to empty gameobject that will be a child of the object that it will draw the circle around.

I want that so I can drag the empty gameobject and change the circle height. That way I can simple duplicate the empty gameobject and have two circles one on ground on higher. and both circle will be the same radius around the parent object the parent object will be the center.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

[ExecuteAlways]
[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class DrawRadiusAroundTurret : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(1, 50)] public int segments = 50;
    [Range(1, 5)] public float xRadius = 5;
    [Range(1, 5)] public float yRadius = 5;
    [Range(0.1f, 5f)] public float width = 0.1f;
    public bool controlBothXradiusYradius = false;
    public bool draw = true;

    [SerializeField] private LineRenderer line;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        CreatePoints();
    }

    public void CreatePoints()
    {
        line.enabled = true;
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
        line.useWorldSpace = false;
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
        line.positionCount = segments + 1;

        float x;
        float y;

        var angle = 20f;
        var points = new Vector3[segments + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < segments + 1; i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xRadius;
            y = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yRadius;

            points[i] = new Vector3(x, 0f, y);

            angle += (380f / segments);
        }

        // it's way more efficient to do this in one go!
        line.SetPositions(points);
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private float prevXRadius, prevYRadius;
    private int prevSegments;
    private float prevWidth;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        // Can't set up our line if the user hasn't connected it yet.
        if (!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        if (!line) return;

        if (!draw)
        {
            // instead simply disable the component
            line.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise re-enable the component
            // This will simply re-use the previously created points
            line.enabled = true;

            if (xRadius != prevXRadius || yRadius != prevYRadius || segments != prevSegments || width != prevWidth)
            {
                CreatePoints();

                // Cache our most recently used values.
                prevXRadius = xRadius;
                prevYRadius = yRadius;
                prevSegments = segments;
                prevWidth = width;
            }

            if (controlBothXradiusYradius)
            {
                yRadius = xRadius;
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

[image: The linerenderer and the script are both attached to the Missles Turrent instead I want them to be on empty gameobject child of the Missles Turrent and that it will keep drawing the same circle around the Missles Turrent but when it will be from the child object I will be able to change the circle height.]

The main goal is to have multiple circles around the Missles Turrent but that I will be able to change the circles height with a simple drag.

Comment: Consider adding a clickable "handle" object that you can drag in the scene view. When it's moved, update the radius of your circle and recalculate the points. It may be more efficient to create a textured quad with a texture of a circle rather than using `LineRenderer`, or even a torus, as those will obey the `transform` hierarchy.

Comment: Solved by adding two children to the turret and on both added linerenderer and the script both objects positions are set  to 0,0,0 now it's working fine.

Comment: nice. And that’s following the patent object when it moves? The last time I used LineRenderer, it didn’t play nice with .transform.

Comment: @3Dave you right. now when moving the parent it will move the two circles with it and you can move each circle on his own, here is a screenshot showing it.  I called the first circle as Bottom Circle in most of the time I will not change it's position. The second child is Moving Circle and this one I will change his height.  https://imgur.com/a/9Pv97RZ

Comment: Cool. I suggest posting that as an answer and includeingany updated code. It could be helpful to others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create empty gameobject/s as children each child position set to 0,0,0
Then adding to each child a linerenderer component and the script.

The script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

[ExecuteAlways]
[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class DrawRadiusAroundTurret : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(1, 50)] public int segments = 50;
    [Range(1, 5)] public float xRadius = 5;
    [Range(1, 5)] public float yRadius = 5;
    [Range(0.1f, 5f)] public float width = 0.1f;
    public bool controlBothXradiusYradius = false;
    public bool draw = true;

    [SerializeField] private LineRenderer line;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        CreatePoints();
    }

    //private void Update()
    //{
    //    
    //}

    public void CreatePoints()
    {
        line.enabled = true;
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
        line.useWorldSpace = false;
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
        line.positionCount = segments + 1;

        float x;
        float y;

        var angle = 20f;
        var points = new Vector3[segments + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < segments + 1; i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xRadius;
            y = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yRadius;

            points[i] = new Vector3(x, 0f, y);

            angle += (380f / segments);
        }

        // it's way more efficient to do this in one go!
        line.SetPositions(points);
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private float prevXRadius, prevYRadius;
    private int prevSegments;
    private float prevWidth;

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        // Can't set up our line if the user hasn't connected it yet.
        if (!line) line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        if (!line) return;

        if (!draw)
        {
            // instead simply disable the component
            line.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise re-enable the component
            // This will simply re-use the previously created points
            line.enabled = true;

            if (xRadius != prevXRadius || yRadius != prevYRadius || segments != prevSegments || width != prevWidth)
            {
                CreatePoints();

                // Cache our most recently used values.
                prevXRadius = xRadius;
                prevYRadius = yRadius;
                prevSegments = segments;
                prevWidth = width;
            }

            if (controlBothXradiusYradius)
            {
                yRadius = xRadius;
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

Screenshot :

[image: Circles]